# Display custom error page

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I have an nginx web server that runs a Laravel application. The web.config and .htacces pages are forbidden pages. When I access the page, I get a 403(nginx) error. Instead, I want a custom html page to be displayed. How can this be done achieved?

Answer (score 2):

With a statement like the following (e.g. in the `server` block) where `/403.html` refers to your error page you want to display.

```
error_page 403 /403.html;
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page